# Adjective that means physically felt

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that can be used in an exchange like this:

> Me: I have a gift for you.
>   Other: Is it the gift of happiness?
>   Me: I was thinking of something much more _____.

The blank would be a word that means something directly, explicitly, physically felt, like a kiss. The word "visceral" comes to mind, but that's:

- > relating to deep inward feelings rather than to the intellect. — [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/visceral)
- > felt in or as if in the internal organs of the body. — [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visceral)

which is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: something much more concrete, like a box of chocolates or theater  tickets.

Comment: In the future please cite your sources. In addition, code formatting should not be used for non-code—use quote format instead. (I have fixed both of these things for you in your post.)

Comment: @Laurel Thank you. StackOverflow is more my thing.

Comment: @KarlG I see which direction you're going, however I'm thinking of a more direct physical interaction like a kiss.

Comment: Something more "moving"?

Comment: Tactile is another possibility, in some contexts.

Comment: Me: I was thinking of something less abstract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was thinking of something much more **[palpable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/palpable)**

> 2. Able to be touched or felt.

[Oxford]

Comment: **Palpable** is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

[tangible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangible) is the first word that comes to mind

also [palpable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palpable)

or [concrete](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concrete)

Answer (score 1):

​My first thought was the word **tangible**:

> [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tangible): **real and not imaginary; able to be shown, touched, or experienced**

---

> [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/tangible): **capable of being perceived by the sense of touch**

---

I think that the word *tangible* fits this context just fine, but you may also consider these two words:

> [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/material): **material**

> **relating to physical objects or money rather than emotions or the spiritual world**

---

> [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concrete): **concrete**

> **clear and certain, or real and existing in a form that can be seen or felt**

---

Though, when it comes to which of these three words is actually used in this exact context, based on [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), we've got just **14 results** for *something more tangible*, **21 results** for *something more concrete*, and... **0 results** for *something more material*.